# How to get first row of 3 specific values of a column using Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table which has ID, FAMILY, ENV_XML_PATH and CREATED_DATE columns. [image: TABLE IMAGE]

| ID | FAMILY | ENV_XML_PATH | CREATED_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 15826841 | CRM | path1.xml | 03-09-22 6:50:34AM |
| 15826856 | SCM | path3.xml | 03-10-22 7:12:20AM |
| 15826786 | IC | path4.xml | 02-10-22 12:50:52AM |
| 15825965 | CRM | path5.xml | 02-10-22 1:50:52AM |
| 15653951 | null | path6.xml | 04-10-22 12:50:52AM |
| 15826840 | FIN | path7.xml | 03-10-22 2:34:09AM |
| 15826841 | SCM | path8.xml | 02-10-22 8:40:52AM |
| 15223450 | IC | path9.xml | 03-09-22 5:34:09AM |
| 15026853 | SCM | path10.xml | 05-10-22 4:40:59AM |

Now there are 18 DISTINCT values in FAMILY column and each value has multiple rows associated (as you can see from the above image).
What I want is to get the first row of 3 specific values (CRM, SCM and IC) in FAMILY column.

Something like this:

| ID | FAMILY | ENV_XML_PATH | CREATED_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 15826841 | CRM | path1.xml | date1 |
| 15826856 | SCM | path3.xml | date2 |
| 15826786 | IC | path4.xml | date3 |

I am new to this, though I understand the logic but I am not sure how to implement it. Kindly help. Thanks.

Comment: Most people here want sample table data as properly formatted text. (I can't read that tiny image text on my laptop screen.)

Comment: okay let me add that

Comment: Done, could you please check the question now?

Comment: Which rows are "the first"? Does this depend on the id, the date or what?

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand.

Comment: You wrote you would like to get the first row for a specific value. So let's say for example, you want to find the first row whose family is CRM. Which of the rows with this family should be the first and should be selected? The row with the highest id, the lowest id, the latest date or what exactly?

Comment: Actually anything is fine. I just need one row from each value in FAMILY column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `RANK` for that. Something like this:

```
WITH  groupedData  AS
(SELECT id, family, env_xml_path, created_date,
RANK () OVER (PARTITION BY family ORDER BY id) AS r_num
FROM      yourtable    
GROUP BY  id, family, env_xml_path, created_date)

SELECT    id, family, env_xml_path, created_date
FROM      groupedData
WHERE     r_num  = 1
ORDER BY  id;
```

Thus, within the first query, your data will be grouped by family and sorted by the column you want (in my example, it will be sorted by id).

After that, you will use the second query to only take the first row of each family.

Add a `WHERE` clause to the first query if you need to apply further restrictions on the result set.

See here a working example: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/X8Rp9QYl)

Comment: Thank you so much. The solution is working as per my expectation.

Comment: @bapun You're welcome. If a solution works like you expected, please don't write comments, but upvote the answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

The question doesn't really specify what 'first' means, but I assume it means the first to be added in the table, aka the person whose date is the oldest. Try this code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM (yourTable) WHERE Family = 'CRM' OR 
Family = 'SCM' OR Family = 'IC' ORDER BY Created_Date ASC FETCH FIRST (number) ROWS ONLY;
```

What it does:

Distinct - It selects different rows, which means you won't get same type of rows at the top.

Where - checks if certain condition is true

OR - it means that the select should choose rows that match those requirements. In the current situation the distinct clause means that same rows won't repeat, so you won't be getting 2 different 'CRM' family names, so it will find the first 'CRM' then the first 'SCM' and so on.

ORDER BY - orders the column in specified order. In the current one, if first rows mean the oldest, then by ordering them by date and using ASC the oldest(aka smallest date) will be at the top.

FETCH FIRST (number) ROWS ONLY - It selects only the very first couple of rows you want. For example if you need 3 different 'first' rows you need to get **FETCH FIRST 3 ROWS ONLY**. Combined with the distinct word it will only show 3 different rows.

Comment: How do you use TOP in Oracle DB's?

Comment: @JonasMetzler I didn't even pay attention that it says oracle, cuz I'm used to browsing through sql-server when I'm here. But I changed the answer. Instead of using TOP at the start of the select, in oracle you do FETCH FIRST number ROWS ONLY

Answer (score 0):

You could use a window function to get to know the row number of each partition in `family` ordered by the `created_date`, and then filter by the the three families you are interested in:

```sql
with row_window as (
  select
    id,
    family,
    env_xml_path,
    created_date,
    row_number() over (partition by family order by created_date asc) as rn
  from <your_table>
  where family in ('CRM', 'SCM', 'IC')
)

select 
  id,
  family,
  env_xml_path,
  created_date
from row_window
where rn = 1
```

**Output:**

| ID | FAMILY | ENV_XML_PATH | CREATED_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 15826841 | CRM | path1.xml | 03-09-22 6:50:34 |
| 15826856 | SCM | path3.xml | 03-10-22 7:12:20 |
| 15826786 | IC | path4.xml | 02-10-22 12:50:52 |